# How do I add a common parent to TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-5, tinymce-plugins

How can I make it so that everything that is entered into tinymce is contained in a common block with the desired id and class? Perhaps there is some property to indicate the parent? For example, I need it to be such a block:

```html
<div id="some-id" class="some-class">
  some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options in the TinyMCE configuration that should do the job:

1. [`body_class`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#body_class) and [`body_id`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-appearance/#body_id) will add custom `id` and `class` parameters to the `<body>` of the HTML generated by TinyMCE.
2. [`forced_root_block`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block) will change the root block which is `<p>` by default.
3. [`forced_root_block_attrs`](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block_attrs) will add custom parameters to all root blocks in the HTML. Thus you can add custom classes and IDs to each and every paragraph of the TinyMCE content.